# Probability formula related to distribution balls in boxes.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**Problem**

Suppose there is a distribution of $N$ distinct balls in $n$ different boxes such that each ball has the same probability to be in any box. Let $A_i=\{\text{the i-th box is not empty}\}$.

(1) Show for all $k=1,...,n$, we have $$V_k=P(A_{i_1} \cap ... \cap A_{ik})=\sum_{j=0}^k {k \choose j}(-1)^j(1-\frac{j}{n})^N.$$

(2) Prove that if $\lim_{n,N \to \infty} \dfrac{N}{n}=\lambda$, then $\lim_{n,N \to \infty} V_k=(1-e^{-\alpha})^k$.

I am trying to show this formula by induction. For $n=2$, we have that $$P(A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2})=1-P((A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2})^c)=1-(P({A_{i_1}}^c)+P({A_{i_2}}^c)-P({A_{i_1}}^c \cap {A_{i_2}}^c)).$$

This last expression equals to $$1-2\frac{(n-1)^N}{n^N}+\frac{(n-2)^N}{n^N}.$$

By a simple calculation, one can verify $$\sum_{j=0}^k {k \choose j}(-1)^j(1-\frac{j}{n})^N=1-2\frac{(n-1)^N}{n^N}+\frac{(n-2)^N}{n^N}.$$

So the hypothesis is true for $n=2$. Now, I've supposed that the statement is true for $k \leq n$ and I've tried to prove it for $k=n+1$ but I couldn't. I would appreciate if someone could help me to finish the problem with an answer or with suggestions and also any hint to do part (2).

Comment: Using `\ldots` instead of periods results in more appropriate spacing.

Answer (score 1):

$(1)$ Rather than using induction, use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle:

\begin{eqnarray*}
P\left(\bigcap A_{i_k} \right) &=& 1 - \sum_{r=1}^{k}{P\left(A_{i_r}^c\right)} + \sum_{r \lt s}{P\left(A_{i_r}^c \cap A_{i_s}^c\right)} - \ldots + (-1)^k P(A_{i_1}^c \cap \ldots \cap A_{i_k}^c)
\end{eqnarray*}

The general term on the RHS, with an intersection of $j$ sets, is a sum of $\binom{k}{j}$ terms of the form:

\begin{eqnarray*}
P\left(\bigcap_{r=1}^{j} A_{i_r}^c \right) &=& P(\mbox{all $N$ balls are in the other $n-j$ boxes}) \\
&=& \left(1 - \frac{j}{n}\right)^N
\end{eqnarray*}

This gives us the required answer:

\begin{eqnarray*}
P\left(\bigcap A_{i_k} \right) &=& \sum_{j=0}^k {k \choose j}(-1)^j(1-\frac{j}{n})^N
\end{eqnarray*}

$(2)$ Firstly,

$$\lim_{n,N \to \infty}{(1-\frac{j}{n})^N} = e^{-jN/n} = e^{-\lambda j}$$

using the known limit (with $k=-j, \,\,x=n, \,\,m=N/n$):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}{(1+\frac{k}{x})^{mx}} = e^{mk}$$[which is the first limit in "Notable special limits" section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_limits).

Therefore,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{n,N \to \infty}{V_k} &=& \lim_{n,N \to \infty}{\sum_{j=0}^k {k \choose j}(-1)^j(1-\frac{j}{n})^N} \\
&=& \sum_{j=0}^k {k \choose j}(-1)^j\lim_{n,N \to \infty}{(1-\frac{j}{n})^N} \\
&=& \sum_{j=0}^k {k \choose j}(-1)^j e^{-\lambda j} \\
&=& \sum_{j=0}^k {k \choose j}1^{k-j} \left(-e^{-\lambda}\right)^j \\
&=& (1 - e^{-\lambda})^k \qquad\mbox{(by the Binomial Thm)}
\end{eqnarray*}